# How to convert target values with pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have some data with a target of 4 values ​​and I want three of these to become part of one single using latin pig.

```
Input:                     Output:
ID     | Target            ID     | Target    
-----------------          -----------------
test1      1               test1      1
test2      1               test2      1
test3      2               test3      2
test4      2               test4      2
test5      3               test5      2
test6      4               test6      2
test7      2               test7      2
```

Someone knows the best way to do it

Comment: which three values must become 2?

Comment: All values 2, 3 and 4, like 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Bincond](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Arithmetic+Operators) to check for target value greater than 1 and if true replace it with the value you want,in this case 2.

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (Id:chararray,target:int);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE Id,(target > 1 ? 2 : target);
DUMP B;
```

Comment: One more question please, in case that target, is a chararray instead of an int. The bincond operator could be used, or is it just for numerical operations and should I use another operator? Of course, would change the squema of the load, to chararray as well.

Comment: you can use it for chararray as well.In that case you will not be able to check for >.you will have to check for "2","3","4".